# I Need a software to make Instant chat on Intranet

Tags: networking, instant-messaging

I am a Network Administrator, and  I am looking for a software or application that allow me to install and configure an instant chat Network to be used by my employees.
Like **Intramessenger** , but something else.!

Any Ideas?

Comment: This question is off topic for several reason, it is for a business/corporate environment, and it is requesting a software recommendation. http://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

What about something like mattermost. It's an open source Slack alternative. There is a web interface, desktop clients and apps for iOS and Android available as well.

http://www.mattermost.org/

Otherwise, Jabber/XMPP server software and clients are available and would probably fit your needs.

http://xmpp.org/

http://xmpp.org/software/clients.html

http://xmpp.org/software/servers.html